# Deep-copying a derived class when its base class has member pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, deep-copy

I am trying to make a deep copy of the object `d` of class `Derived` as in the code below:

```cpp
class A {
public:
   int m_int;
   A* clone() {
      return new A(*this);
   }
};

class Base {
public:
   A* m_a;
   virtual Base* clone() {
      A* new_a = new A();
      new_a = this->m_a->clone();
      Base* clone = new Base(*this);
      clone->m_a = new_a;
      return clone;
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   double m_dbl;
   virtual Derived* clone() {
      return new Derived(*this);
   }
};

int main() {
   Derived* d = new Derived();
   d->m_dbl = 1.234;

   A* a = new A();
   a->m_int = -1;

   d->m_a = a;

   //clone d
   Derived d_copy = d->clone();

   //changing values of d's attributes must not affect d_copy
   a->m_int = 10;
   d->m_dbl = 3.456;

   //check d_copy
   cout << "m_int " << d_copy->m_a->m_int << endl;
   cout << "m_dbl " << d_copy->m_dbl << endl;
}
```

output:

```cpp
m_int 10 //wrong, should be -1;
m_dbl 1.234 //correct
```

As you can see, simply returning `new Derived(*this)` in Derived's `clone()` method is wrong since it does not deep-copy `m_a`.

If I "bring down" the deep-copying of `m_a` from `Base` to `Derived` then I will get the correct answer:

```cpp
   virtual Base* clone() = 0;

   ...

   virtual Derived* clone() {
      A* new_a = new A();
      new_a = this->m_a->clone();
      Derived* clone = new Derived(*this);
      clone->m_a = new_a;    
      return new Derived(*this);
   }
   //gives out m_int = -1
```

If this is the case does this mean that each time I create further derived classes from `Derived`, I always have to "bring down" the contents of `clone()` to them?

Also, if for example `Base` has two derived classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`, does this mean that I have to deep-copy the members of `Base` in each of them?

Any other ways to approach this?

Comment: why is `m_a` a pointer? If it was an object you'd get deep copies for free

Comment: There's a memory leak in `Base::clone`.

Comment: Why don't you make deep-copying copy constructors? Copying is what they're for, after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider of implementing the copy constructor that always is doing deep copy. In such case your `clone` implementation will always be trivial:

```
class Base {
public:
   A* m_a;
   Base(const A& other)
       : m_a(other.m_a->clone())
   {       
   }

   virtual Base* clone() {
      return new A(*this);
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   double m_dbl;
   Derived(const Derived& other)
       : m_dbl(other.m_dbl)

   virtual Derived* clone() {
      return new Derived(*this);
   }
};
```

If you don't want to change the behavior of the default constructor (you want the default constructor to make shallow copy for example) the alternative is to move copy implementation to a `CopyTo` method, so you can reuse it:

```
class Base {
public:
   A* m_a;
   static void CopyTo(const Base& from, Base& to)
   {
        to.m_a = from.m_a->clone();
   }

   virtual Base* clone() {
      Base* result = new Base();
      CopyTo(*this, result);

      return result;
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   double m_dbl;

   static void CopyTo(const Base& from, Base& to)
   {
        Base::CopyTo(from, to);
        to.m_dbl= from.m_dbl;
   }

   virtual Derived * clone() {
      Derived * result = new Derived ();
      CopyTo(*this, result);

      return result;
   }

   virtual Derived* clone() {
      return new Derived(*this);
   }
};
```